# Discrete Wigner function for single qutrit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-information

My goal is to calculate the discrete Wigner function for a single qutrit, based off of the discussion near page 4 of [Veitch et. al.'s paper on the resource theory of stabilizer computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7171). Given the generalized Heisenberg-Weyl operator

$$T_{a_x a_z}=\omega^{{-a_x a_z}/2}Z^{a_z}X^{a_x}$$

where $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/3)$, $a_x,\,a_z\in \mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_3$, and taking the clock and shift operators to be
\begin{align} &X|j\rangle =|(j+1)\mod d\rangle\notag\\
&Z|j\rangle =\omega^j|j\rangle\end{align}

the phase point operator is then

$$A_0=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{{\bf u}\in Z_d^n \times Z_d^n}T_{\bf u}$$

Then, defining $A_{\bf u}=T_{\bf u}A_0 T_{\bf u}^\dagger$, the discrete Wigner function is given by $$W_{\bf u}(\rho)=\textrm{Tr}(A_{\bf u}\rho)$$

I thought I'd start with ${\bf u}=(0,0)$ first, and thus $W_{00}(\rho)=\textrm{Tr}(A_0\rho)$. However, right off the bat, when I calculate $A_{\bf u}$, I get

\begin{align}
A_0&=\frac{1}{3}\left\{
I+X+X^2+Z+\omega^{-1/2}ZX+\omega^{-1}ZX^2+Z^2+\omega^{-1}Z^2 X+\omega^{-2}Z^2X^2
\right\}\notag\\
&=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{3}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\\ \frac{1}{3}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Which I know is incorrect, because it is non-Hermitian. However, I've checked the solution over and over again, and I still get the same matrix. What, exactly, am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why should $_0$ be hermitian, as defined? In the abstract, did you use *=*, †=$^2$, †=$Z^2$?

Comment: ...meant =   above...